# Removal of Specific element value and its duplicate and replace it with only one value in xml by xslt code

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Below is my sample XML file facing issue with removing duplicates for                                                particular node  if its value is "H" then it will remove all duplicates in Test5 having value as H else for other value test5 can have values no need to remove any duplicates .Any Help highly appreciated:Below is Scenario:

Scenario1: For Test3 value keep only one H value in Test5 if more then 1 H is available then remove other H and just keep one and do not remove other Test5 value and duplicates for Test3 i.e E,T,M etc

```
<Report_Data>
<Report_Entry>
 <Test1>ABC</Test1>
 <Test2>ABC</Test2>
  <Test3>000</Test3>
   <Test4>ABC</Test4>
   <Test5>H</Test5>
   <Test6>Match</Test6>

    </Report_Entry>
        <Report_Entry>
         <Test1>ABC</Test1>
           <Test2>ABC</Test2>
         <Test3>000</Test3>
         <Test4>ABC</Test4>
           <Test5>E</Test5>
          <Test6>Match</Test6>

            </Report_Entry>
            <Report_Entry>
         <Test1>ABC</Test1>
        <Test2>ABC</Test2>
        <Test3>000</Test3>
         <Test4>ABC</Test4>
         <Test5>H</Test5>
         <Test6>Match</Test6>
        </Report_Entry>

         <Report_Entry>
        <Test1>ABC</Test1>
           <Test2>ABC</Test2>
           <Test3>000</Test3>
           <Test4>ABC</Test4>
             <Test5>H</Test5>
               <Test6>Match</Test6>
                 </Report_Entry>
                   </Report_Data>
```

Expected output :

```
               <Report_Data>
           <Report_Entry>
           <Test1>ABC</Test1>
           <Test2>ABC</Test2>
          <Test3>000</Test3>
           <Test4>ABC</Test4>
           <Test5>H</Test5>
          <Test6>Match</Test6>
             </Report_Entry>
                  <Report_Entry>
                     <Test1>ABC</Test1>
             <Test2>ABC</Test2>
            <Test3>000</Test3>
            <Test4>ABC</est4>
               <Test5>E</Test5>
             <Test6>Match</Test6>
           </Report_Entry>
              </Report_Data>
```

Used XSLT for Grouping and removing duplicates:

```
           <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
            <xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"                            version="1.0">
               <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

                <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

             <xsl:key name="Test5-H" match="Test5" use="."/>


                <xsl:template match="Report_Data">
             <catalog>
                 <xsl:apply-templates/>
                   </catalog>
                 </xsl:template>

             <xsl:template match="Report_Entry">
                  <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <Test5>
            <xsl:for-each select="Test5[count(. | key('Test5-H', .)[1]) = 1]">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                </xsl:if>
              </xsl:for-each>
               </Test5>

                 </xsl:copy>
             </xsl:template>

               </xsl:transform>
```

Issue with above code is it removing all duplicated for test5 but i only need it will remove if test5 is having value H .

Comment: please edit you answer to include your expected output from this input. Good luck.

Comment: Please post your attempted XSLT and your desired output when asking for help with XSLT.  Also, please indicate the version of XSLT you intend to use.

Comment: @DanField I ahve updated my question sorry i am new here so not knowing how to post code n all .

Answer (score 0):

You say you want to remove specific elements, but your current template that matches `Report_Entry` starts off by always copying the `Report_Entry`

```
<xsl:template match="Report_Entry">
    <xsl:copy>
```

What you probably need to do, is add an `xsl:if`, using your existing expression for grouping, here

```
<xsl:template match="Report_Entry">
  <xsl:if test="Test5[count(. | key('Test5-H', .)[1]) = 1]">
    <xsl:copy-of select=".">
   </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

However, it might be slightly more logical to change your key to this, as you are effectively grouping `Report_Entry` elements by `Test5` elements

```
 <xsl:key name="Test5-H" match="Report_Entry" use="Test5"/>
```

Then, as you are removing elements, you have a template like this

```
 <xsl:template match="Report_Entry[not(count(. | key('Test5-H', Test5)[1]) = 1)]" />
```

This would need to be combined with the identity template though.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key name="Test5-H" match="Report_Entry" use="Test5"/>

 <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Report_Entry[not(count(. | key('Test5-H', Test5)[1]) = 1)]" />
</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: Really appreciate help.

But still below scenario will make you understand more.
Scenario1:
For Test3 value keep only one H value in Test5 if more then 1 H is available then remove other H and just keep one and do not remove other Test5 value for Test3 i.e E,T,M etc.

Comment: Can you amend your original question with these updated scenarios, because it currently doesn't mention anything about Test3 in the question. Thank you!

Comment: In your question, all `Test3` elements have the value `000` so I am not clear what you want to do with it.